# python load json file and print values in different line

Tags: python

This is `file.json`:

```
[
    {"date": "1402/11/03", "time": "18-21", "count": 5},
    {"date": "1402/11/04", "time": "12-15", "count": 2},
    {"date": "1402/11/05", "time": "10-13", "count": 4},
    {"date": "1402/11/06", "time": "09-12", "count": 7},
    {"date": "1402/11/06", "time": "15-18", "count": 3},
    {"date": "1402/11/07", "time": "17-20", "count": 2},
    {"date": "1402/11/07", "time": "14-17", "count": 1},
    {"date": "1402/11/09", "time": "13-16", "count": 1}
]
```

This is my python code:

```py
with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

new_list = [f'Date --> {x["date"]}, Remaining counts --> {x["count"]}' for x in data]
```

I'm not looking for this:

```
print('This is our data:')
for i in new_list:
    i
```

I'm looking for a way to store the `i`s into a variable, so that this line would have the same output as above:

```py
print(f'This is our data:\n{new_var}')
```

Comment: What is your question?  It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: @FrankYellin `Mohsen Fatemi`'s answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `join` method from strings.

```
new_var = '\n'.join(new_list)

print(new_var)
```